# how to pass the array to gridview in yii2

Tags: php, arrays, gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

im using yii2 framework

I have array coming from controller to the view.

```
 public function actionProducts()
{
$product = Yii::$app->httpclient->get('http://localhost/MWSProducts/src/MarketplaceWebServiceProducts/Samples/GetMatchingProductSample.php');

        $array1 = str_replace("ns2:","",$product);
        $array=json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($array1)),true);           

        return $this->render('products',['array'=>$array]); 
}
```

In the above code im converting xml to an array.
The **$array** has the array, and im passing it to view called **products**. Now i want to display that array in the view in Gridview, Since im new to yii2 im unable to do this, it says i have to use some dataprovider, but im not getting how to do this.

Can anyone please help me in this how do i display the array in gridview. Thank you

Thanks for the answer..

Actually its a amazon product array im fetching it from the Product API, we cant define any predefine attributes like id and all, since its different for each product. this is how the array looks like.

```
  Array
  (
   [GetMatchingProductResult] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [ASIN] => 0886467918
                        [status] => Success
                    )

                [Product] => Array
                    (
                        [Identifiers] => Array
                            (
                                [MarketplaceASIN] => Array
                                    (
                                        [MarketplaceId] => A21TJRUUN4KGV
                                        [ASIN] => 0886467918
                                    )

                            )

                        [AttributeSets] => Array
                            (
                                [ItemAttributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [Author] => Kipling, Rudyard
                                        [Binding] => Hardcover
                                        [Edition] => Har/Cas
                                        [Format] => Import
                                        [Label] => Imprint unknown
                                        [Languages] => Array
                                            (
                                                [Language] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [Name] => english
                                                                [Type] => Published
                                                            )

                                                        [1] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [Name] => english
                                                                [Type] => Original Language
                                                            )

                                                        [2] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [Name] => english
                                                                [Type] => Unknown
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [Manufacturer] => Imprint unknown
                                        [PackageDimensions] => Array
                                            (
                                                [Weight] => 1.74
                                            )

                                        [ProductGroup] => Book
                                        [ProductTypeName] => ABIS_BOOK
                                        [PublicationDate] => 1988-05-02
                                        [Publisher] => Imprint unknown
                                        [SmallImage] => Array
                                            (
                                                [URL] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/412CsE6Mb8L._SL75_.jpg
                                                [Height] => 75
                                                [Width] => 50
                                            )

                                        [Studio] => Imprint unknown
                                        [Title] => Jungle Book ("Read Along")
                                    )

                            )

                        [Relationships] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [SalesRankings] => Array
                            (
                                [SalesRank] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [ProductCategoryId] => book_display_on_website
                                                [Rank] => 709468
                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [ProductCategoryId] => 1318084031
                                                [Rank] => 14260
                                            )

                                        [2] => Array
                                            (
                                                [ProductCategoryId] => 1318083031
                                                [Rank] => 47016
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the array contain the data like a dataProvider . you can use arrayDataProvider http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider.html   eg (from yii2 guide):

> ```
>     $data = [
>         ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'name 1', ...],
>         ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'name 2', ...],
>         ...
>         ['id' => 100, 'name' => 'name 100', ...],
>     ];
>
>     $provider = new ArrayDataProvider([
>         'allModels' => $data,
>         'pagination' => [
>             'pageSize' => 10,
>         ],
>         'sort' => [
>             'attributes' => ['id', 'name'],
>         ],
>     ]);
> ```

a brief guide to dataprovider http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html

in your case

```
    public function actionProducts()
    {
    $product = Yii::$app->httpclient->get('http://localhost/MWSProducts/src/MarketplaceWebServiceProducts/Samples/GetMatchingProductSample.php');

            $array1 = str_replace("ns2:","",$product);
            $array=json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($array1)),true);           



            $provider = new ArrayDataProvider([
                'allModels' => $array,
                'pagination' => [
                    'pageSize' => 10,
                ],
            ]);

            return $this->render('products',['array'=>$array]); 
    }
```

Refer to sample above where the array $data contain id, name and suppose your arrayDataProvider  is in the var $array and have id,name too in gridview you should have

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $array,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',
        'name',
        .....

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
        'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:84px; font-size:18px;']],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: OK what should i give in the view now?

Comment: I have added a suggestion for griview

Comment: Yeah i want in grid view itself,  What if we dont have the id,name in the array? Because every array will have different attributes here.  Then how i pass it

Comment: consider the possibility of a show different column based on the "type" of array .. you can set the column in proper $varsColumnArray .. and the set this to the column part of the gridview .. but this is another question ..

Comment: Works perfect. But what about if you need to use a search model also?

Comment: @Jonyx4  if you need  a  search model .. then you should  create a proper search function  for manage properly the params you need .. foe example you could add  a new searchFunction to an existing seacrhModel with the query  you need.